# RewriteUrl in Phoenix / Plug / Cowboy?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy, plug

How to rewrite an Url in phoenix?
For example rewrite all requests to `//www.app.com/xyz` to `//app.com/xyz`

Is there an easy option for it, like *force_ssl*? Has anyone an idea, where to PLUG it in? Has plug an option for it?

Comment: Why would you do this on application level? Usually, such rewrites are done on the web server level config.

Comment: true, in this case cowboy is my top level server, no other reverse proxy, thanx

Comment: Then you probably want to use [Cowboy routing](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/routing/) for that. When I’ve said “why on app level,” I meant that `Plug` is way too deep inside the application for this kind of task.

Comment: yeah, I gree, but I am a bit confused how to do it with cowboy routing. Can you give a small example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use a Custom Plug

You can write a custom `Plug` to handle your scenario. Here's an example:

```
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.RewriteURL do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Phoenix.Controller

  @redirect_from "www.app.com"
  @redirect_to   "app.com"

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(%Plug.Conn{host: host, port: port, request_path: path} = conn, _) do
    if host == @redirect_from do
      conn
      |> redirect(external: "http://#{@redirect_to}:#{port}#{path}")
      |> halt
    else
      conn
    end
  end
end
```

Now just add it to the top of your pipeline in `web/router.ex`:

```
pipeline :browser do
  plug MyApp.Plugs.RewriteURL
  plug :accepts, ["html"]

  # Other plugs...
end
```

---

**This is a basic proof of concept, but should work for the majority of the cases.**

*You'll have to modify this code according to your exact requirements since it is missing some functionality. For example, it doesn't pass the request's `query` or `params` to the redirected URL. It also does a basic redirect, so you might consider using a [307 redirect](https://httpcodes.co/status/307/) if you would like to keep the original request method without changing it to GET.*

Comment: looks good, lets see if there will be some other, more general approaches